# Apache rewrite rules working on one server but give 500 error on the other host

Tags: apache, http, url, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+_[0-9]+)/json(/)?$ /widget_json.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This rule seems to be working fine on one of my websites at -> 
http://domainsoutlook.net/5_68528/json/1/

But the same rule produces 500 error on the link at ->
http://cheernuts.com/5_68528/json/1/

Both of the servers have mod_rewrite enabled...

Can you please help me fix this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that errors are turned on in PHP and that should show you the errors. Else some other php error might be the reason.